# JS Countdown timer with days:hours:minutes

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I found a neat timer but I need to customize it a bit to work for my project, I tried to change javascript code so it would be a countdown until the weekend and start again from ex: 6days:23hours:59minutes, but I failed miserably

I also would like to know how possible could I add a third row called days

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYEBjP

JS code

```
var Clock = (function(){

    var exports = function(element) {
        this._element = element;
        var html = '';
        for (var i=0;i<6;i++) {
            html += '<span>&nbsp;</span>';
        }
        this._element.innerHTML = html;
        this._slots = this._element.getElementsByTagName('span');
        this._tick();
    };

    exports.prototype = {

        _tick:function() {
            var time = new Date();
            this._update(this._pad(time.getHours()) + this._pad(time.getMinutes()) + this._pad(time.getSeconds()));
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                self._tick();
            },1000);
        },

        _pad:function(value) {
            return ('0' + value).slice(-2);
        },

        _update:function(timeString) {

            var i=0,l=this._slots.length,value,slot,now;
            for (;i<l;i++) {

                value = timeString.charAt(i);
                slot = this._slots[i];
                now = slot.dataset.now;

                if (!now) {
                    slot.dataset.now = value;
                    slot.dataset.old = value;
                    continue;
                }

                if (now !== value) {
                    this._flip(slot,value);
                }
            }
        },

        _flip:function(slot,value) {

            // setup new state
            slot.classList.remove('flip');
            slot.dataset.old = slot.dataset.now;
            slot.dataset.now = value;

            // force dom reflow
            slot.offsetLeft;

            // start flippin
            slot.classList.add('flip');

        }

    };

    return exports;
}());

var i=0,clocks = document.querySelectorAll('.clock'),l=clocks.length;
for (;i<l;i++) {
    new Clock(clocks[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper:

```
var TimeHelper = function(days, hours, minutes, callback) {

    this.subtractMinute = function() {
        minutes = (minutes + 60 - 1) % 60;
        if (minutes === 0) {
            hours = (hours + 60 - 1) % 60;
            if (hours === 0) {
                days = (days + 24 - 1) % 24;
                if (days === 0) {
                    days = 24;
                    hours = 0;
                    minutes = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        callback(days, hours, minutes);
    }
}

function refreshUI(days, hours, minutes) {
    //refresh my ui elements
}

var timeHelper = new TimeHelper(24, 0, 0);
```

And then you can call `timeHelper.subtractMinute` once/minute this on every minute

Comment: I did not really want to study your code, as it is over-complicating the issue. If you use my code, implement a function which will serve as callback and you generate an infinite loop with the setInterval function.